# Outlook, Folder EntryId changes at runtime

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, mapi, office-automation

I have an issue with sentfolder EntryId from Outlook.

I work with sentfolder

I have 2 Accounts.
My account (dafault(Exchange)): all works perfect.

The second account(additional(Exchange)) has:

```
outboxMailEntryID = 00000000A24FEAFFFFB93C47A13126365D132558010010E2685A8E0AC440B14F77F5EE5275A5000000BBA**800000**0
sentMailEntryID = 00000000A24FEAFFFFB93C47A13126365D132558010010E2685A8E0AC440B14F77F5EE5275A5000000BBA7FF0000
```

At runtime the sendfolder get an other EntryId. It changes

from:

```
IsOutputExtended check folder.Name = **Gesendete Elemente** folder.EntryID = 00000000A24FEAFFFFB93C47A13126365D132558018010E2685A8E0AC440B14F77F5EE5275A5000000BBA**8000000**
```

to:

```
IsOutputExtended check folder.Name = **Gesendete Elemente** folder.EntryID = 00000000A24FEAFFFFB93C47A13126365D132558018010E2685A8E0AC440B14F77F5EE5275A5000000BBA**8000100**
```

I do follows:

```
    private static bool IsOutputExtended(MAPIFolder currentFolder)
    {
      PropertyAccessor propAcc = null;
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folders folders = null;
      MAPIFolder rootFlder = null;
      Store store = null;

      if(currentFolder == null)
        return false;

      try
      {
        store = currentFolder.Store;

        const string PR_IPM_OUTBOX_ENTRYID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x35E40102";
        const string PR_IPM_SENTMAIL_ENTRYID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x35E20102";
        
        rootFlder = store?.GetRootFolder();
        folders = rootFlder?.Folders;

        string sentMailEntryID = "";
        string outboxMailEntryID = "";
        propAcc = store?.PropertyAccessor;

        try
        {
          if (propAcc != null)
          {
            object entryOutbox = propAcc.GetProperty(PR_IPM_OUTBOX_ENTRYID);
            outboxMailEntryID = propAcc.BinaryToString(entryOutbox);
            object entrySend = propAcc.GetProperty(PR_IPM_SENTMAIL_ENTRYID);
            sentMailEntryID = propAcc.BinaryToString(entrySend);
          }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          CobraMain.Logger.Warn("Error in IsOutputExtended by Check PR_IPM_OUTBOX_ENTRYID and PR_IPM_SENTMAIL_ENTRYID for " + currentFolder.Name, ex);
        }

        if(currentFolder.EntryID == sentMailEntryID || currentFolder.EntryID == outboxMailEntryID)
          return true;
....
```

Have someone an idea what happens?

Thanks.

Comment: After PC restart it is again: IsOutputExtended check folder.Name = Gesendete Elemente folder.EntryID = 00000000A24FEAFFFFB93C47A13126365D132558018010E2685A8E0AC440B14F77F5EE5275A5000000BBA**8000000**

Comment: How did you add the second store to the profile - by configuring another account in Outlook or just adding it a secondary store in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep the `EntryID` property value in the code. Instead, use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method of the `Store` class which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

Answer (score 0):

You should always treat entry ids as black boxes. Never compare entry ids directly, always use `Namespace.CompareEntryIDs`.

Keep in mind that multiple entry ids can refer to the same MAPI object. The MAPI provider is free to store whatever it deems necessary inside its entry ids, including flags that can depending on how the object was opened.